# SQL Error (1415): Not allowed to return a result set from a function

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE FUNCTION value_economy(gnp_old float, gnp_new float)
RETURNS float
BEGIN
    DECLARE result float;
    DECLARE result1 float;

    SET result1 = (gnp_new - gnp_old) / gnp_old * 100;

    SET result = result1;

        IF(result >= 0) THEN
            SELECT CONCAT("UP");
        ELSE
            SELECT CONCAT("DOWN");
        END IF;

    RETURN result1;

END;|
```

why this error?

Comment: Presumably because you have `SELECT` statements that don't save the results anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation on  [user-defined functions in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-function-udf.html)
you can only return values of type `{STRING|INTEGER|REAL|DECIMAL}`

If you want to get a selected resultset you have to define a `procedure` but not `function`.